# Blazor Project: Creating a Dynamic Ordered List Component

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I'm working on a Blazor project and I want to create a OrderedList component that can dynamically generate li and display data. Specifically, I'm looking to implement a feature where I can retrieve the ListItems and loop through them to get the properties for the items that will be displayed in the ul.

For each ListItem, I'd like to be able to create a Ordered List header with the name of the property and also extract the property values for the body of the ul. What's the best way to achieve this functionality in Blazor?

I've been trying to implement this, but I'm not sure how to proceed. Any guidance, code examples, or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
<OrderedList Items="pagedResult.Items">
    <ListItem Header="Name" Property="Name" />
    <ListItem Header="Actions">
        <button type="button">
            Edit
        </button>
    </ListItem>
</OrderedList> 


<ul>
@foreach (var item in Items)
        {
            <li>
                @foreach (var listItem in ListItems)
                {
                    <span>
                        @item.GetType().GetProperty(listItem.Property).GetValue(item)
                    </span>
                }
            </li>
        }
</ul>

@code {
    [Parameter] public List<OrganizationResponse> Items { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment ListItems { get; set; }
}


<!--  ListItem.razor -->
<div>
    @ChildContent
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string Header { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string Property { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public bool Sortable { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  You talk about lists and mixed in with that is tables.   Where's `OrderedList`?  Can you please split your code out into separate blocks for each component so it's clearer what code is in which component.

Comment: I apologize for any confusion. Let me clarify how to loop through ListItem inside the OrderedList component and access Header, Property, and Sortable parameters.